# windows phone, background tasks and new message alerts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task

Unfortunately the API that i am working with does not have a push notification service and it will be too costly for me to create one.

I wanted to know if the periodic task with a few **if statements** around it is the usual way to report new messages? (imagine its like facebook chat, that's pretty much what this API is for).

**The aforementioned if statements may be:**

- If unread message count is greater than the message count i saved to memory from last API ping, then do toast notification.

Is there a proper way of doing this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You are just right. Why do you think it's not a good idea?

Comment: I imagined there would be some special way of doing it. That's good news. Thanks!